# How to persist MultiPoligon Objects in Hibernate-Spatial and Postgis

Tags: java, hibernate, polygon, hibernate-spatial

How can i make a

```
com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.MultiPolygon
```

objects as they occur e.g. from GeoTools using Hibernate-Spatial into a Postgis database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Hibernate Spatial 5 an example table (using the Annotations-Method) could look like:

```
@Entity
public class MultiPolygon {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "geometry(MultiPolygon,4326)")
    private com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.MultiPolygon polygon;

    // ... Getters - setters 
}
```